# How to add lines to <li> elemtents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a tree-view or something like that.My problem is that I don't have any ideea in how to drag a line like this:
[image: this should it look like]

this is the code I have:

```
<ul>
   <li>el1
     <ul>
        <li>el1.1
          <ul>
            <li>el1.1.1</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>el1.2</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li>el2</li>
</ul>
```

and so on. Is it possible to do what I want with css? I am search for 4 hours and I didn't find anything.
PS: i'm not good at all at css.

Also, another question: is this possible with js to create a treeview? just simple js, not complicate plugins or stuff like that.

Comment: there are jquery plugins available for treeview

Comment: @Ehsan yes, i know, but not that was my question. my question is how can i add lines like in the image with css?

Comment: if the work is already done why you want to make it from scratch by putting effort

Comment: look for the `jstree` plugin or goog it. I reckon you need that for this.

Comment: because i have developed some jquery plugins for that list,like inline edit, or auto-submit to some iframe forms, and i tried to add some plugins but they aren't compatible, so I need pure css code for the lines

Comment: You can not simply get the lines as show in the image and with the mark shared by you. In most of the widgets ``border-top: 1px solid black; height: 0`` kind of style would have been used.

Comment: @sarbbottam so you say that it's not possible with pure css?

Comment: I've seen it done using borders on psuedo-elements.

Comment: @Jhon Not exactly what you wanted. Check this out, http://jsbin.com/nuwibopi/1/edit

Comment: yes, it's the same css as @Roko and it's exactly what I was searching for. Thnx;

Comment: Well you did not mention that extra long vertical for el1 at this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/nuwibopi/1/edit) in the image shared by you. This [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/nuwibopi/1/edit) is a forked version of @Roko. I have not changed much, but deleted the line ``<li>el2</li>``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like: http://jsbin.com/qalir/1/edit

```
ul{
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    border-left:1px solid #444;
}
ul li{
    padding-left:15px;
    position:relative; /* to allow :before pseudo element be absolute */
}
ul li:before{
    content:" ";
    height:1px;
    width:15px;        /* same as LI's padding */
    background:#444;
    position:absolute;
    top:0.7em;         /* ~half line-height */
    left:0px;          /* to properly align left */
}
```

Comment: it's perfect, just what i needed! Thanks a lot.